# Datepicker does not accept future date

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I have added one date picker to a site like:

```
<input type="text" id="popupDatepicker" placeholder="Select Date" name="from_date" class="input" size="50" />
```

Script:

```
$(function() {

$('#popupDatepicker').datepick();

});
```

but this date picker is not accepting the future date. it only accepts past and current date. if we try to select future date it shows starting date of 1970 AD as output after submitting the form.

Comment: How does PHP relate to the question? You should instead specify the client-side scripting library you are using.

Comment: Make sure you provide code that actually demonstrates the problem. Does the problem really appear on a page that contains nothing but the code you posted? Also specify the version of the library (presumably jQuery UI) that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

May be due to jQuery and jQueryCalendar versions you use. Just try the source in [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default).